# Excel: Losing decimal separator when converting from strings to number

Tags: c#, excel, casting, formatting

I am trying to read some values from several files and save them in a new .xlsx file with different grouping. I devised a very simple setup to test different formatting and behavior with null values. I always open just-created file in Excel to see outcome. So far no problem.

However in my test-case I can achieve either: A) save the test values as they are (strings) or B) force Excel to regard them as numbers with given format (good), but lose decimal separator (very bad & strange).

I had traced problem to the last line in a code snippet below. The idea of self-assign is from another post somewhere here at SO but right now I am unable to find it.

If the line is commented-out the results are as in a `string[,] contents` only they are formatted as text (and Excel complains about this with "number formatted as text" message). If I uncomment it, the numbers are regarded as numbers but lose decimal separators. Also the problem might be a fact that I am in Czech Republic and decimal separator is `,` which might trouble Excel. Moreover, reading the values from start into a `double[,] contents` is out, since I need to indicate whether value is absent (with empty cell). And `double?[,] contents` crashes Excel...

Please, haven´t you met this behavior before? I would like to 1) be able to indicate missing value and 2) have contents of cells formatted as a number, not text. Can you help me how to achieve this?

```
excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelWorkBooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
excelWorkBook = excelWorkBooks.Add();
excelSheets = excelWorkBook.Sheets;
excelWorkSheet = excelSheets[1];           //Beware! Excel is one-based as opposed to a zero-based C#

string[,] contents = new string[,] {  { "1,23", "2,123123123", "3,1415926535" }, { "2,15", null, "" } };

int contentsHeight = contents.GetLength(0);
int contentsWidth = contents.GetLength(1);

System.Globalization.CultureInfo currentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
string numberFormat = string.Format("0" + currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + "00E+00");

for (int column = 0; column < contentsWidth; column++) {
    excelWorkSheet.Columns[column + 1].NumberFormat = numberFormat;
}

Excel.Range range = excelWorkSheet.Range[excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1], excelWorkSheet.Cells[contentsHeight, contentsWidth]];
range.Value = contents;
// range.Value = range.Value;  //Problematic place
```

EDIT: I tryed to change NumberFormat from `0,00E+00` to something like `0,0`, `0.0`, `#,#` for the sake of test, but with no success. Either crash (decimal dot) or remains as a text.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Excel. You are trying to pass strings formatted for the wrong locale. The decimal in Anglosaxon countries is `.`. Your sample uses `,`, typically used in European countries. I bet your locale isn't French, German or Greeek.

Comment: *Instead* of trying to hard-code the separator, pass the numbers as *numbers*. ie, use a decimal or double array, and pass the values *unformatted* to Excel. It *can* accept numbers as well as text

Comment: Even petter, instead of using interop use a library like Epplus to generate a valid `xlsx` file easily, without even having Excel installed. You can fill a sheet with `sheet.LoadFromCollection(myNumbersCollection)` or `LoadFromDataTable`.

Comment: I am from Czech Republic, and also currentCulture says `cs-CZ`. What puzzles me most is that it does not remain same with self-assigment.

Comment: And you have a US locale as most developers? Anyway, don't use strings. Excel understands numbers. As I said, the best option is to use Epplus though

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: As I tryed to explain in the post, `double[,]` is not possible, I have approximatelly 3/4 cells empty (i.e. no value at all) and excel chokes to death on `double?[,]`.

Comment: it *is* possible. You are just doing it wrong. For example,  you are trying to avoid looping by assigning to an entire range at once.

Comment: Please, can you write a piece of code to show me how to do it? With `double?[,] contents = new double?[,] {1, 2, null};` I had so far allays thrown an Exception. Also with the possible I meant that I need to make empty cells (e.g. by null or empty string).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to convert numbers to text before writing them to a cell. Excel understands numbers. A further problem is that the code is trying to set the array as the value of an entire range, as if pasting into Excel.

It's possible to set numbers, even nulls, directly using a simple loop, eg

```
double?[,] contents = new double?[,] { { 1.23, 2.123123123, 3.1415926535 }, 
                                       { 2.15, null, null } };
int contentsHeight = contents.GetLength(0);
int contentsWidth = contents.GetLength(1);
...
for(int i=0;i<= contentsHeight; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j <= contentsWidth; j++)
        excelWorkSheet.Cells[i+1,j+1].Value = contents[i,j];
```

Instead of using Excel through Interop though, it's better to use a package like [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus) to generate `xlsx` files directly without having Excel installed. This allows generating real Excel files even on web servers, where installing Excel is impossible.

The code for this particular problem would be similar:

```
var file = new FileInfo("test.xlsx");
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Rules");
    for(int i=0;i<= contentsHeight; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= contentsWidth; j++)
            ws.Cells[i+1,j+1].Value = contents[i,j];
    pck.Save();
}
```

EPPlus has some convenience methods that make loading a sheet easy, eg LoadFromDataTable or LoadFromCollection. If the data came from a DataTable, creating the sheet would be as simple as:

```
var file = new FileInfo("test.xlsx");
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Rules");
    ws.LoadFromDataTable(myTable);
    pck.Save();
}
```

LoadFromDataTable returns an `ExcelRange` which allows cell formatting just like Excel Interop.

Comment: I was hoping to solve this without succumbing to per-cell basis, since I am writting 14 sheets each 5 columns times 4500 lines. Concerning speed consult this: http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Write-data-to-an-Excel-worksheet-with-C-fast.aspx . However if I have to work on per-cell basis, I can do so directly in an Excel. Web availability is not something I care of and since it is for in-house usage where virtually all computers have Excel ...

Comment: Interop is a *lot* slower than generating a file directly. If you care about performance you shouldn't be using interop in the first place. If you want to generate *reports*, you should be using eg Reporting Services or SSIS.

Comment: Where do you load the data from? If the data is loaded from the database, eg as a DataTable, you could simply use LoadFromDataTable 15 times. There's also a `LoadFromDataReader` for loading directly from a fast-forward reader

Comment: I am picking data from files. They are about some measurements. However, those data needs to be sorted since data from several files needs to be joined and sorted.